# Inequality of elements of hat matrix

Tags: regression, linear-model

We have a linear model 
\begin{align}
Y=X\beta + \varepsilon
\end{align}
where $X$ is $n \times p$ ($n > p$) matrix of full rank. All assumptions of linear model hold.

I have to prove inequality which is connected with the elements $h_{ij}$ of the hat matrix $H=X(X'X)^{-1}X'$. The inequality is:
\begin{align}
0 \le h_{ij}^{2} \le 0.25,
\end{align}
where $i \neq j$. Do you have any ideas how to deal with it?

Comment: Do you mean that for an _arbitrary_ projection matrix this inequality holds, or you need to show it for a specific projection matrix, in which case you must know something specific about the $X$ matrix?

Comment: Use the fact that $H=H^2$ -write out what that means.

Comment: This question has been asked also in math SE, here : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/561287/inequality-of-elements-of-hat-matrix. I have voted to close.

Comment: *Please do not cross-post*; this is against SE policy. Figure out where you want this question to be & delete the other version.

Comment: Ok, sorry for this. I have already deleted it from stackexchange.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to use this tip with $H=H^{2}$. Can you be a little more precise?

Comment: "*All assumptions of linear model have power.*" power against what? --- what does this mean? Do you mean 'All assumptions of the linear model hold'? If so, it seems odd to use a word like 'power' which has a very particular meaning in a statistical context, when a more common, and less likely to be misleading, English expression already exists.

Comment: Ok, I made a correction.

Comment: I suspect this statement should hold for any idempotent matrix, i.e. any matrix $H$, for which $H^2=H$.

Comment: Perhaps but how to prove it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $H$ be an idempotent symmetric matrix. Then $H^2=H$ and for each $i=1,...,n$ we have

$$\sum_{j=1}^nh_{ij}^2=h_{ii},$$

where we simply write the elements of the main diagonal $H^2$. We can rewrite this equality as

$$\sum_{j\neq i}h_{ij}^2=h_{ii}-h_{ii}^2 \>.$$

The quantity $h_{ii}-h_{ii}^2$ can be at most $1/4$ and we immediately get our desired result.

**P.S.** The inequality cannot be improved without additional assumptions, as illustrated by the following idempotent matrix

$$\begin{bmatrix}1/2 & 1/2\\1/2 & 1/2\end{bmatrix} \>.$$

Comment: And $h^2_{ij} \ge 0$, for $i \ne j$, follows trivially from $h_{ii}= ||\mathbf{H}\mathbf{e}_i||^2$.

Comment: @Skull: Or more trivially...because it is the square of a real number. :-)

Comment: ;) Sure. So remember my comment when someone happens to ask why we have $h_{ii} \ge 0$ ...

Comment: @Skullduggery note you write $h_{ij}$ for $i\neq j$ (sic!) follows from $h_{ii}=...$. Nevertheless the fact that $h_{ii}\ge 0$ is a useful one.

Comment: @mpiktas: Thanks for being clear. So please enter my statement directly after the second equation of your answer and bear in mind that $h_{ii} \le 1$ follows trivially from $||\mathbf{e}_1||=1$.

Comment: I have additional question: How can we prove that $$h_{ii} \ge \frac{1}{n}$$

Comment: @Skullduggery $x(1-x)$ is at most 1/4 for any $x$. It is not necessary to consider specifically $x>0$.

Comment: @JohnSnow, simple simulations show that this inequality is false.

Comment: @mpiktas: Thanks for math101. Honestly? Basically your answer did not explicitly establish that $h_{ii} \le 1$. Only then your claim holds.

Comment: Sorry. You're right. of course. I went a little astray with my thought on the $h_{ii}$ and their properties ...